# Select box to display current week

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm creating a Call back form for my companies website, rather than using the standard HTML5 datepicker. I would like to achieve something like they have here next to the "Date to call" label.

https://www.scottishpower.co.uk/account/click2call.process?execution=e1s1

I am currently working with Bootstrap 2 and here is the input snippet I have currently and the URL to view is: http://temp.tefl.org.uk/callback

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Date To Call</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select>
            <option>Monday (date)<option>
            <option>Tuesday (date)<option>
            <option>Wednesday (date)<option>
            <option>Thursday (date)<option>
            <option>Friday (date)<option>
        <select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they used drop down option instead of input tag..

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing the option elements.

try the following code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var x = new Date().getDay();

            var elem = $("div.controls select option")[x];
            $(elem).prop("selected","selected");

        });

    </script>

    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Date To Call</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <select>
                <option>Monday (date)</option>
                <option>Tuesday (date)</option>
                <option>Wednesday (date)</option>
                <option>Thursday (date)</option>
                <option>Friday (date)</option>
            <select>
         </div>
     </div>
```